# Shift focus back to previous content on page after closing a success banner on top of the page

Tags: reactjs, typescript, components, accessibility

I have a react application that is of multiple pages, and those pages reuse a banner component.

Whenever there is an action performed on the screen, and result will appear on top about the success/error information banner.

here I am facing difficulty in switching focus back to the previous element on the page ( not the one which caused the banner event, the user might continue on page after banner ) when the user dismisses the banner ( it is not auto dismiss).

Using onDismiss on the banner to track the active element is going to the body of the page.

Can anyone help me here?

PS: Apologies, as I can't share the code here.

I tried by passing document.activeElement to handleClose.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is to have a callback executed on banner dismiss and the page where the element that needs to set focus will handle it with combined use of document.getElementById() or document.querySelector() if the ID is not set.

Pseudo example

*Main page* that's rendering the bar

```
<MessageBar onSubmitCallback={this._exeCallback}

private _exeCallback = (): void => {
  const elemToFocus = document.getElementById('${element-id}')
    if (elemToFocus) {
      elemToFocus.focus()
    }
}
```

`Message bar` adds a callback (optional) to its props

```
type MessageBarProps = componentProps & { onSubmitCallback?: () => void}

private _onDismiss = () => {
  if (this.props.onSubmitCallback} {
  this.props.onSubmitCallback()
}
```